# Python Mandrill: Invalid API Key

Tags: python

This is my first time to use mandrill. I have imported mandrill and provided my API key. but they key is rejected on every action i want to do (ping or send message). There is little documentation on the error:

```
     import mandrill
     MANDRILL_API_KEY = '298b4fbe4e08c------------'
     mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
     result = mandrill_client.urls.list()
```

I am trying to follow the documentation as it is on python 3

Comment: API key is invalid so it is obvious you will see this error.

Comment: i just created the API (and the ---- are just placeholders if thats what you are refering too).

Comment: Not **--** placeholder I thought API key is expired or wrong but as you said it is correct and newly generated then it should have worked.